# Where is it better to invoke methods to retrieve Extra values?

Tags: android

In the Android application I use extra value to define the previous activity in MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val s: String? = intent.getStringExtra("prev_activity")
}
```

Since the return to the activity can be make repeatedly, the onCreate() method is not suitable. Tried to place the getStringExtra() method in the onResume() method of MainActivity:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val s: String? = intent.getStringExtra("prev_activity")
    // s == null
}
```

But it returns null. Then placed getStringExtra() in the onNewIntent() method of MainActivity:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    val s: String? = intent.getStringExtra("prev_activity")
}
```

This works well when creating an intent in a previous activity, but when you return from the previous activity using the back button on the navigation panel, the method onNewIntent() is not invoke. Why? And where should I invoke getStringExtram() method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "But it returns null" -- then the activity was created with an `Intent` that lacks the extra. That has nothing to do with when you call `getStringExtra()`. "But it returns null" -- no, it only works if you already had the activity created via some *other* `Intent`, and another `startActivity()` call got routed to this particular activity instance (due to flags or manifest settings). For the first `Intent`, `onNewIntent()` is not called. "Why?" -- why would it be? A new `Intent` was not delivered to the activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks You for the comment! I will look in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to get extra value inside the onCreate() method. Mostly you want the value when you come from the previous activity and onCreate() method call once in activity lifecycle.

Don't do this onResume() because it's call again and again if you lock and unlock your device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The method onCreate() of MainActivity is called only once when the application launch, but there can be many returns from other activities to MainActivity. What to do in this case?

Comment: Think in my case it is better to use SharedPreferences